# Why aren't all my documents updated in Firestore?

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I'm using python for trying to add a field to more than 750 documents in a firestore collection, but when trying to do this, only my first 55 documents get updated. I'm assuming this happens because of the firestore write limits but don't really get why.

### COLLECTION STRUCTURE

[image]

**Note:** `actividades` is an array with a size around of 20 elements and each element has only 3 properties.

[image]

### CODE

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore

cred = credentials.Certificate('avancesAccountKey.json')
default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
db = firestore.client()

count = 0
avances = db.collection('avances').get()
for e in avances:  
    db.collection('avances').document(e.id).update({
        'vigente': False
    })
    count += 1

print(count) # count is 55 when trying to update, 757 otherwise
```

What is exactly happening and how I can solve this?

Comment: Which of the Firestore [documented limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas) do you think you're running into?  Are you suggesting the count is different when you perform the update as opposed to leaving it commented out as you show now?

Comment: It is diferent. The count is 757 without the comments. I don't really know why is happening, but i'm thinking that is because of one of the Firestore limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't mutate the collection as you iterate through it. Instead, fetch the document references and then iterate.

```
count = 0
documents = [snapshot.reference for snapshot in db.collection('avances').get()]
for document in documents:
    document.update({u'vigente': False})
    count += 1
```

Reference: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/6033

**Update:** It appears the Firestore python client does have a [20 second timeout for the generator returned from a query](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/6043).

Comment: why is bad mutating the collection while iterating?

Comment: It's a general good practice not to mutate the thing you're iterating over, because it can lead to unexpected results. Classic example is a [with a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list) but it applies here, too.