# How to download large number of documents from Google cloud Firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore

I have a collection `data` in Google cloud Firestore. This collection has over 200K documents. I want to export each document as a line to a file.

I created a script which is working fine for 50K rows. After that its crashing with following exception. How can I get all documents?

I saw something called offset, but not sure its helps in my situation.

Code Snippet:

```python
from google.cloud import firestore
import os

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "key.json"


db = firestore.Client()
col = db.collection(u'data')
docs = col.get()

with open('data.bak', 'a') as f:
    for doc in docs:
        f.write(u'{} => {}'.format(doc.id, doc.to_dict()))
        f.write('\n')
```

Exception:

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "down_db.py", line 13, in <module>
    for doc in docs:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1beta1/query.py", line 744, in get
    for index, response_pb in enumerate(response_iterator):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 81, in next
    six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
google.api_core.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: 503 The datastore operation timed out, or the data was temporarily unavailable.
```

Comment: How about loading data in smaller chunks?

Comment: I am not inserting data to Firestore,but downloading it. I don't have control over limiting data or where clauses.

Comment: That's also what I'm talking about, downloading data in smaller chunks. Oh, you have. Check [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) out.

Comment: Thanks @AlexMamo, I will try that. Later I will try [query cursors](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/query-cursors)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why aren't all my documents updated in Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52360438/why-arent-all-my-documents-updated-in-firestore)

Answer (score 3):

The Cloud Firestore python client has a 20 second timeout for `get()`. Try breaking up the work or try fetching all the document references and then iterating.

```
docs = [snapshot.reference for snapshot in col.get()]
for doc in docs:
        ...
```

[Github issue regarding timeout](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/6043)

Answer (score 2):

there's another approach which I think would work using gcloud command line tool, this will require you to use the Bucket storage and BigQuery, both are pretty easy to get going.

1. Export the collections using the [gcloud firetore export function](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/export-import) in the terminal:

```
gcloud beta firestore export gs://[BUCKET_NAME] --collection-ids=[COLLECTION_ID_1],[COLLECTION_ID_2]
```

Your whole collections will be exported to a GCS Bucket, the data format is the same as Cloud Datastore thous readable through BigQuery so..

2. Load the data from [GCS Bucket to Bigquery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-firestore), the exported Firestore Collection will live as a table in BigQuery
3. Query the table form BigQuery with something like `select * from [TABLE_NAME]`, BigQuery then has an option to download the query result as CSV

Answer (score 0):

> I created a script which is working fine for 50K rows.

That limit is precisely the [number of documents that you can read on a project on the free/Spark plan](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#free-quota) of Firebase. If your project is on the free plan, you'll need to upgrade it to read more documents per day.

Comment: Thanks @Frank van Puffelen.
I am using Firestore form Google cloud project. Which has $300 credits and I guess the row limts does not apply on GCP projects.